# SSRS Report showing incorrect Legend and data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have this script in SQL here that will calculate the date.

```
CASE
    WHEN Overdue = 1 THEN
    (CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, A.TARGET_DATE, GETDATE()) <= 30 THEN '0-1 Month'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, A.TARGET_DATE, GETDATE()) <= 182 THEN '1-6 Months'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, A.TARGET_DATE, GETDATE()) <= 365 THEN '6-12 Months'
        ELSE '> 12 Months'
    END)
END AS Category,
```

but when I try to show it on a chart it will show like this:

[image: chart]

The result I desire is to show the legend based on my category script.
Even though there are datas in the resultset that meet the conditions I set, the output of the chart shows a different data. I don't even know where the 98% come from and it doesn't show the other legend that I set on the category script

Comment: So have you checked your data? Based on the nested `CASE WHEN` expressions and the displayed chart I'd assume that 98% of rows have `Overdue != 1` and the other 3% are `> 12 months` making a grand total of 101% (aren't `float`s and rounding wonderful?)

Comment: you're right i just noticed that the total is 101%, i focused too much on the 98%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the total of 101% was because the data on my table are mostly Null hence the 98%.

I fixed this by removing the rows that has a null value in order not to have an inconsistent value on the chart.